# Show that: the column rank of a matrix $A ∈ Mat(n × m; F)$ equals the rank of the linear mapping $(A◦) : F^m → F^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Show that: the column rank of a matrix $A ∈ Mat(n × m; F)$ equals the
>   rank of the linear mapping $(A◦) : F^m → F^n$

The column rank of a matrix $A$ is the dimension of the subspace of $F^n$ generated by the columns of $A$. There are $m$ columns in total and I know that row rank=column rank for all matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the linear map associated to $A \in M_{n \times m}(\mathbb{F})$ by $T_A \colon \mathbb{F}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^n$. We have

$$ \mathrm{rank}(T_A) = \mathrm{dim} \,\mathrm{Im(T_A)} = \mathrm{dim} \{ T_A(e_1), \ldots, T_A(e_m) \} $$

where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{F}^m$. Note that $T_A(e_i)$ is just the $i$-th column of $A$ and conclude.